# Can someone identify this plant please?

Tags: identification

Ground level Spanish plant ]caused skin irritation(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAIZ2.jpg)[image]

Answer (score 1):

Asparagus acutifolius. Images [here](https://www.google.ca/search?biw=1280&bih=631&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=vctAW_rBJITBjwTI_5LwBg&q=asparagus%20acutifolius&oq=asparagus%20acu&gs_l=img.3.0.0j0i30k1j0i24k1.23228.23823.0.25772.3.3.0.0.0.0.163.444.0j3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.3.443...0i8i30k1.0.oeJ3NJOlwRU).

Comment: no need for links, if someone wanted to google for more information they can